# How to handle download links in webview

Tags: android, webview

OK, sorry for the noob question but I have searched and I can not seem to get this to work. I would like to call my site from a webview but I need the download links to actually download the file. Here is what I have so far:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.mapleleaf.mp3download.R;

public class AppWallFragment2 extends SherlockFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle        

savedInstanceState) {
    View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_wall2, container, false);
    WebView webView = (WebView)inflate.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    final ProgressDialog mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),  

"Loading", "Please wait for a moment...");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(mProgress.isShowing()) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("http://anime.appcreator.org");
    return inflate;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `onDownloadStart` function in the WebViewClient

```
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
    //Do something with this URL (like queue a download)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, where do I add this?

Comment: And do I need this for every link that I want to download? For example if the page my webview is calling has several mp3's?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code snippet:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, 
            String contentDisposition, String mimetype, 
            long contentLength) {
        //TODO: Handle your download task here.
    }
});
```

For more detailed please refer to [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setDownloadListener%28android.webkit.DownloadListener%29).